# String Matching: Computing the longest prefix suffix array in kmp algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-matching

[KMP algorithm for string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).
Following is the [code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/) I found online for computing the longest prefix-suffix array:
Defination:

```
lps[i] = the longest proper prefix of pat[0..i] 
              which is also a suffix of pat[0..i].
```

Code:

```
void computeLPSArray(char *pat, int M, int *lps)
{
    int len = 0;  // length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    int i;

    lps[0] = 0; // lps[0] is always 0
    i = 1;

    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    while(i < M)
    {
       if(pat[i] == pat[len])
       {
         len++;
         lps[i] = len;
         i++;
       }
       else // (pat[i] != pat[len])
       {
         if( len != 0 )
         {
           // This is tricky. Consider the example AAACAAAA and i = 7.
           len = lps[len-1]; //*****************

           // Also, note that we do not increment i here
         }
         else // if (len == 0)
         {
           lps[i] = 0;
           i++;
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Can I use `len = len-1` instead of `len = lps[len-1]`?
because len always counts the prefix length like from [0 .. someIndex]. Then why use lps for assignment here? Following are the cases for which I tested which work fine(first line is the pattern and subsequent two lines are the result for original and modified assignment to `len` ) :

```
a  a  a  b  a  b  c  
0  1  2  0  1  0  0  
0  1  2  0  1  0  0 

a  b  c  b  a  b  c  
0  0  0  0  1  2  3  
0  0  0  0  1  2  3  

a  a  b  c  b  a  b  
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  
0  1  0  0  0  1  0
```

Code here with both variations written : http://ideone.com/qiSrUo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following a case for which it does not work:

```
i     0  1  2  3  4  5
p     A  B  A  B  B  A 
c1    0  0  1  2  0  1
c2    0  0  1  2  2  3
```

The reason being:

```
At i=4, len=2 
p[i]='B' and p[len]='A' //Mismatch!
lps string upto i=3: AB(0-1 prefix), (2-3 suffix)
-------------------------------
i=4
Next charecter: B
len=2 // longest prefix suffix length 
Charecter looking for : A (=p[len])
```

So upto i=3 we had AB(0-1) as the prefix that matched with suffix AB(2-3), but now at i=4 there is a mismatch so we see that we **can't** extend the original prefix(0-1) so the position to be checked is the prefix found prior to "AB" which is done by lps[len-1] < -1 as the array starts from 0  > and this is not necessarily len-1 as we may need to step back further than that to get the new longest prefix suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best explanation I have ever seen.Example in it will answer your question clearly.

[Knuth–Morris–Pratt(KMP) Pattern Matching(Substring search)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTJr8OvyEVQ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is MY KMP code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(void){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        int n = s.length();
        int arr[n];
        arr[0] = 0;
        int len = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<n;){
            if(s[len]==s[i]){
                len++;
                arr[i++] = len;
            }
            else{
                if(len!=0){
                    len = arr[len-1];
                }
                else{
                    arr[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<arr[n-1]<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Time Complexcity is O(N)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the intuition behind this algorithm too, refer to below video on YouTube. This is the clearest explanation I've come across for this algorithm.

[The longest prefix suffix array in kmp algorithm](https://youtu.be/tWDUjkMv6Lc)